# RAD Studio 10.4.1 my first iOS app error when attempting to run 'Unable to create process: /Applications/PAServer-21.0.app/Contents/MacOS/dbkosx_27_0'

Tags: ios, delphi-10.4-sydney, paserver, mac-in-cloud

I am trying to build my first multi-platform application using RAD Studio 10.4.1 (Delphi).  Very simple one button app.

My development environment:

- RAD Studio version: 10.4.1 (with latest Combined.Hotfix from 12/25)
- Xcode version 13.7
- Xcode simulator 13.7
- MacOS version: 10.15.7
- PAServer version 12.1.10.5

I am using a MacInCloud account with root access.  The PAServer connection is established successfully when I attempt to debug the app with target platform iOS Simulator 13.7, however, I consistently encounter the following error:

**The following error was returned: 'Unable to create process: /Applications/PAServer-21.0.app/Contents/MacOS/dbkosx_27_0'**

I launch the PAServer app using the root user because I thought there might be a permission issue.
I downgraded XCode, from newest version in the App store (using SDK 14.3) to 13.7, as I learned RAD Studio 10.4.1 is not compatible with the 14.3 SDK.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wrote Jan 2021: Simulator is not longer running! This is what I got from the support:

"The iOS simulator compiler generates 32 bit code so if your Xcode is running on Catalina or above, it is not possible to start the simulator on these operating systems because they only support 64 bit code. Also there seem to be serious stability problems running Delphi apps on the simulator on macOS versions that support 32 bit.

I would therefore advise against using the simulator. At this time we have not committed to a timeframe to releasing a 64 bit simulator."

This also means: the MacInCloud is not longer useful, because you need a real IOS-device on a 64bit Intel-MAC or you get a old 32bit Intel-MAC and use the simulator there (with "serious stability problems"). It seems the simulator is not useful at all for Delphi development.